# PHP - Parse sections between braces from text file

Tags: php, parsing

I have the DHCP lease file from my pfSense as a text file and I need to parse some data from this using PHP.

To give an example, here is how the file looks like:

```
lease 192.168.15.13 {
starts 3 2014/11/12 23:51:05;
ends 4 2014/11/13 00:06:06;
cltt 3 2014/11/12 23:51:05;
binding state active;
next binding state free;
rewind binding state free;
hardware ethernet 8d:3a:96:91:a0:51;
uid "\001\200\352\226\001\240\341";
client-hostname "iPhone";
}
server-duid "\000\001\000\001\000\000\000H\000\015\271)p\335";

lease 192.168.15.12 {
starts 3 2014/11/12 23:51:53;
ends 4 2014/11/13 00:06:54;
cltt 3 2014/11/12 23:51:53;
binding state active;
next binding state free;
rewind binding state free;
hardware ethernet 8c:e6:5f:26:6d:fe;
uid "\001\200\346P&]\376";
client-hostname "Mike";
}
lease 192.168.15.15 {
starts 3 2014/11/12 23:40:34;
ends 3 2014/11/12 23:55:35;
tstp 3 2014/11/12 23:55:35;
cltt 3 2014/11/12 23:40:34;
binding state free;
hardware ethernet 84:58:8b:d7:44:10;
uid "\001\204x\213\207D\020";
}
```

Has anybody an idea how to extract the sections between the braces, starting with

> lease 192.168.25.xx {

till

> }

??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("\{(.*)\}", $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it like this:

$string = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $dhcpFile );
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $string, $matches);

First I remove all breaks and then I apply the regexps!